# Laptop surface vibrating when rubbing over it

Tags: safety, adapter, grounding

Because my previous HP laptop adapter stopped working, I got a new one. But if I use this one, I feel a kind of vibration when I rub over my laptop's surface. I don't have this if I work on battery, and I also didn't have this with my old adapter. It doesn't vibrate from itself, only when I rub over it.

What is this? And can it damage me, my laptop, or any devices I plug in (like USBs)?

My new adapter is not grounded, but my previous one was. Might this be the reason?

Comment: I have experienced small shocks on metallic parts in similar cases. And it feels something like a vibration when you rub over these metallic parts..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the lack of grounding might be a reason.

If there is an X capacitor internally it can cause a current flow that is large enough to be perceptible.

If, where you are, your power has one pin 'hot' wrt ground and the other 'neutral' wrt ground, as well as a non-polarized plug/receptacle, you can try reversing the power pins and see if it goes away.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, reversing the pins does not work. Can the thing that causes this vibration damage me or my computer?

Comment: I am always nervous about safety (both personal and the attached equipment) with low-cost no-name Chinese aftermarket power supplies. I would have to say either are possible. An exact (genuine) replacement is safer.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent this problem when designing a wall adapter?

Comment: @MattB. Grounding will prevent the problem. There might be other ways, but perhaps specific to the electrical system the OP has.